# How to increase size of couchbase document in the WebUI. Its limit is set to 2.5 kb by default

Tags: couchbase

I am not able to create a document of size greater than 2.5 kb in the Couchbase WebUI. Can we remove the size limit?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can remove the document length as well-
you have to edit documents.js file and path of this file is -

C:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\lib\ns_server\priv\public\js\documents.js

on this function isJsonOverLimited(json) you have to false the length limit.
like-

```
function isJsonOverLimited(json) {
  //return getStringBytes(json) > self.docBytesLimit;
    return false;
}
```

Thanks,hope this help...

Comment: The other option is in that file is the value to edit the UI looks for of what to limit the size to. I personally would rather change a variable than code.